# Font awesome icons not working in IE after deployment

Tags: internet-explorer, deployment, font-awesome

Font-awesome icons are working fine in localhost on chrome, firefox and IE (we use IE8 in our project). When deployed into the server, the icons appear on chrome, but not in IE when we run the application. I used some glyphicons too. They appear on IE even after deployment. What could have gone wrong with font-awesome icons. I have checked the mime types too. Both .woff and .eot are added. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, use Fiddler or your browser developer tools to monitor network traffic and ensure that no resources are returning any 404 (not found), etc, errors.

I have also been bit by something similar when the production site is running HTTPS, but the fontawesome.css file is attempting to access the netdna.bootstrapcdn.com site via HTTP.  Follow up with more information about your current configuration and I will try to elaborate.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I was using MS Visual studio 2010 and the build-action property for that file was set to 'none' instead of 'content'. When I changed it to 'content', it worked.